# cannot kill node processes on ec2 instance

Tags: node.js, process, kill

I cannot kill a node processes on my amazon ubuntu ec2 instance.
Here's what I've tried

```
ps aux | grep node --returns a process id
sudo kill -9 process id
```

each time it says no process found and then after

```
ps aux | grep node
```

the process has a new id

`top` shows that the process does not exist also.

I also tried these

```
killall node
pkill node
```

I also rebooted the server same problem.
pm2 was installed, but I uninstalled it.

I also discovered that on looking up the parent processes of the node process using

```
ps -o ppid=the process id
```

there are two parents a sshd and a bash process

Comment: dumb question: When you run the `ps aux|grep node` how many results are you showing? Are you attempting to kill the process from you `ps aux` command?

Comment: 1 process. I'm killing only after the ps aux command with kill -9 ...

Comment: Are you trying to kill the process for your grep? For example if I run `ps aux|grep banana` I get back one process

Comment: So I tried banana and it has the same behavior and same parents.  Does grep return itself if it can't find anything. That seems to be an odd behavior.  But your experiment proved that's what's happening.

Comment: If you were running a node app you would get two results back. 1 the node app and 2 the grep.

Comment: Thanks for solving the case of the phantom node process.

Comment: This may help if you want to omit that record from your command [`ps aux|grep "[n]ode" `](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/74185/how-can-i-prevent-grep-from-showing-up-in-ps-results)

Comment: This is much better. Thanks.